# How to Enable TLS 1.0 encription for API integration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, salesforce

Salesforce is going to disable SSL 3.0 encryption on 7th November for all the sandbox instances and later for production instances.More Details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-disabling-SSL-3-0-encryption&language=en_US&elq_mid=7926&elq_cid=11328125).

In sandbox environment, my .Net client application using OAuth 2.0 Web Server flow and salesforce APIs to communicate with salesforce.  How could I verify that my API integration is using SSL 3.0/TLS 1.0/1.1 encryption and how could I change the encryption protocol? Where could I found these settings?

More info:

I am using System.Net.WebRequest class for making call to salesforce API.
And for fetching data from salesforce I am using WebClient.

I am not sure where to specify SSL 3.0/TLS 1.0 encryption while making call on WebRequest and Webclient?

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            string query = "SELECT ID,NAME,LASTMODIFIEDDATE FROM Outage_Schedule_c WHERE IsDeleted = False ORDER BY ID ASC NULLS FIRST".Replace(' ', '+');
            var response = client.DownloadString(instanceUrl + "/services/data/v20.0/query?q=" + query);

            return response ;
        }


 private static string HttpPostRequest(string uri)
   {
       var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
       request.Method = "POST";
       var resp = request.GetResponse();
       var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
       return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been addressed separately on the Salesforce StackExchange site in [Ensuring my application complies with SSL3.0 being disabled?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54960/ensuring-my-application-complies-with-ssl3-0-being-disabled)

You can explicitly set TLS support using  [System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this, the SalesForce documentation could do with being updated...

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications